# Pytest keep missing return line in the same function that has been ran multiple time

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I'm doing a project in django and I have 2 serializer like this:
parent_serializer.py

```
class ParentSerializer(serializer.Serializers):
    action = ChildSerializer()
```

child_serializer.py

```
class ChildSerializer(serializer.Serializers):
    ...
    def validate(self, attrs):
        ...
        **return attrs**
```

There is an if statement in the validate function and i wrote all the tests needed for the if statement, but pytest coverage keep saying that it missed the return statement line (return attrs), which imo, supposed to run in every test case.

I did try everything possible but nothing works. Please help me on that one

Comment: How are you ensuring `validate()` gets executed?

Comment: In the project we have like 10 test cases using this serializer, some of those do asserting value after calling `is_valid` function (in django the validate() will always be executed inside `is_valid`)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
So basically I have to cover else case in the validate function. I have a statement look like `if action in: ...` which actually never happened in real case, but coverage still call missing for it.